# Follow questions in RSS

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to follow newly added questions in RSS format? I didn't find a way. Couple of users could enjoy this possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be no direct link to it on the homepage or the questions page, but https://chess.stackexchange.com/feeds seems to be what you're looking for; it's an RSS version of the [Newest Questions page](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest).

[image]